# Calling OLEDBConnection.Refreshing on a loop prevents connection refresh from finishing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm trying to determine when a connection refresh is complete. I'm looping and checking if the connection is still refreshing every 5 seconds.

As long as it keeps looping and checking, the connection never gets out of it's refreshing state. Even though it will say "xxx Rows Loaded", it immediately finishes if the script is stopped.

```
Private Sub RefreshButton_Click()

    For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        'Refresh this connection
        objConnection.Refresh

        Dim endTime As Date
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 1

        Do While objConnection.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing

            endTime = DateAdd("s", 5, Now())

            Do While Now() < endTime
                DoEvents
            Loop

            i = i + 1
            Me.RefreshButton.Caption = "Refreshing..." & i
        Loop

    Next

    MsgBox "Finished refreshing all data connections"
```

How can I loop like this to check if the connection is still refreshing, without preventing it from finishing?

**Edit**: Had the loop run a bit and then end, the connection immediately finishes refreshing after I close the MsgBox but never before, even if I loop forever with `DoEvents.

**It looks like it does not finish refreshing till the VBA script has finished executing?**

Comment: Have you tried checking the "objConnection.State" to see if it refreshing?

Comment: @nbayly Would I be checking for a string that matches "Refreshing" ? The documentation on these things is a bit spotty, and I'm having a hard time locating it.

Comment: @nbayly I just get "Object does not support this property or method" when attempting to use objConnection.State

Comment: Did you try `objConnection.OLEDBConnection.Refresh` or `objConnection.Refresh` instead? It looks like (although I'm not sure) that you are calling the refresh method and refreshing property on different objects.

Comment: May take some testing but the Refreshdate is updated after each query.  Could compare that to the previous refreshdate.

Comment: @RyanWildry the `objConnection` does not have a refreshing property to see if it's currently refreshing, but the `OLEDBConnection` does. Calling `objConnection.OLEDBConnection.Refresh` seems to have the same effect as `objConnection.Refresh`.

Comment: What exactly is the *purpose* of the code?  The connection is designed to refresh in the background.

Comment: @Comintern As mentioned in the OP, I'm trying to determine when a refresh is complete. There is no action being taken on that right now, since that's out of the scope of this question. However, I will be updating the user on the status of each connection's refresh, among other things.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell  you may also want to look at Application.OnTime since it will not refresh until the current block of code has executed.   This would allow you to run a macro at a given time increment. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx

Comment: I get that you want to determine if a refresh is complete, but you're yielding to the user in your loop anyway with each `DoEvents` call, so they're perfectly free to do whatever would get in the way of "other things".  If all you need to do is stop it from running asynchronously, set `BackgroundQuery = false` and just let it block.